# SQL Server - how to convert yyyy and m to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have two columns :

- year - **YYYY** - data type `int`
- month - **M** - data type `int`

[image: example for the results]

My question is how to convert these columns to date format, assuming as day the first day of month?

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields...

Comment: Which day in month?

Comment: the first day  1

Comment: Jarlh- thanks fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `DATEFROMPARTS` function, like below:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 1) FROM MyTable
```

Last parameter is for day part, so you can change it from 1 to anything you want :)

Comment: Note: It cannot handle remoting to servers with a version below SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Benzi You're right. Do you have version so you can use this query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following (earlier SQL Server 2012):

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Year]) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, [month]) + '-' + '01' AS DATE) 
FROM table_name
```

Since SQL Server 2012 you can also use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [month], 1) FROM table_name
```

> **demo:** https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ab24b45c9270d2880cda468aa422237

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
select datefromparts(year, month, 1) from table_name
```

here is the reference : [DateFromparts](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)